# User class: How do I handle different user "subjects" and still keep my single responsability principal?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, php, object-oriented-design, single-responsibility

I have a User class, this class handles things like:

- login (UserAuthenticateModel)
- Handle user sessions: user login tokens, fetching user from session if set in session, ect' (UserSessionsModel)
- Fetch & Set user data to populate $this user object. (UserFetchModel)
- Update & change my user data (to this user object - and in the database) (UserUpdateModel)

I'm asking out loud and please correct me if I'm wrong:

1. **Is every point a single responsibility of some sort of "something that handle only one thing" inside the "User" class and needs a different class?**
2. **Does my User class need to be under "classes" folder, since it's just an object of "something", and my other classes like "UserSessions" and "UserAuthenticate" should be considered as a model?**

I'll describe 2 examples with some code:

1. Setting sessios: Insead of just pasting a whole bunch of code in my construct that "does something with sessions", I use a UserSessionsModel specifically with the method that does whatever it has to do - get data from session if exist. single responability - Setting/changing my user sessions, and populating my user object. and some of this session handling methods might be used elsewhere (example 2).

Code ex:

```
User class 
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        # look for a user in the session if set
        $this->getFromSession();
    }

    public function getFromSession() 
    {
        # Create UserSession obj
        if ( !$this->UserSessions instanceof UserSessions )
            $this->UserSessions = new \myapp\Models\User\UserSessionsModel();

        $this->UserSessions->getUserFromSession($this);
    }

}

class UserSessionsModel {

    public function getUserFromSession(User $User)
    {
        if (Session::exists(Config::$user)) {

            $session = unserialize(Session::get(Config::$user));

            $User->id             = $session->id; 
            $User->firstName      = $session->firstName; 
            $User->lastName       = $session->lastName; 
            $User->userName       = $session->userName; 
            $User->email          = $session->email; 
            $User->lastLogin      = $session->lastLogin; 
            $User->password       = $session->password; 
            $User->ip             = $session->ip; 
            $User->loginTimestamp = $session->loginTimestamp; 
            $User->isLoggedIn     = $session->isLoggedIn; 

            return $User;
        }
    }



 public function setUserToSession(User $User)
    {
        Session::set(Config::$user, serialize($User));
    }

}
```

2. Logging in: 
   This has 2 parts:

   - First to authenticate the user credentials
   - Set security sessions (token, loggedin flag, ect'.) - using the UserSessionModel from example 1 - since it handles the same "subject". 
     So both are under the login method (one insice an other or separately - this example handles them the first way)
     and both are 2 different responsibilities - one is checking a user authentication, the second is handeling the sessions/tokens.

code ex:

```
User class {

    // after setting $this->username & $this->password to this object
    public function login()
    {
        if ( !$this->UserAuthenticator instanceof \myapp\Models\User\UserAuthenticatorModel )
            $this->UserAuthenticatorModel = new \myapp\Models\User\UserAuthenticatorModel();

        return $this->UserAuthenticatorModel->login($this);
    }
}


class UserAuthenticatorModel extends Model
{

    public function login(User $User)
    {
        try {

            # Connect to new database with $User->username & $User->password
            ... 

            # If status is connected 
            if ($newConnection) {

                # Check for user credentials data 
                $userData = $this->UserLoginValidation($User->userName, $User->password); 

                # If the result isn't a valid array - EXEPTION  
                if ( (!is_array($userData)) || (empty($userData)) )
                    throw new LoginException("Invalid username ({$User->userName}) or password ({$User->password})");

                if ($userData["require_password_change"] === 1) {
                    $this->set($User, $userData);
                    return true;
                }

                $this->set($User, $userData);
                # Set logged-in security sessions
                $User->UserSessions = new UserSessionsModel();
                $User->UserSessions->setSecuritySession($User);
                # Set User obj to session
                $User->UserSessions->UserToSession($User);

                # Update last_login for this user
                $this->updateLastLogin($User->id, $User->loginTimestamp);

                return true;

            } else {
                throw new LoginException('User does not exist');
                return false;
            }

        } catch (LoginException $e) {
            $e->log($e);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

*Using PHP here btw.*

Answer (score 2):

I would split this up differently. NOTE: I'm not using any particular language below, the syntax is just used to highlight the organizational ideas.

Authentication should be it's own thing. I normally have authentication return authentication data, and use that authentication data to get the current user. The authentication token can be bound to future requests in lots of ways, but for the sake of this example, I'll have the authentication data passed in.

```
class AuthenticationRequest {
    async AuthData login(credentials: Credentials) {
    }

    logout(authData: AuthData) {
    }
}
```

Now that authentication is done, I'll use another request class for getting and setting the user.

```
class UserRequest {
    async User fetchCurrentUser(authData: AuthData) {
    }

    async User updateUser(user: User, authData: AuthData) {
    }
}
```

This turns `Credentials`, `AuthData`, and `User` into plain old data objects.

```
class Credentials {
    userName: String
    password: String
}

class AuthData {
    token: Data
    loginTimestamp: Date
    userId: String // Maybe not needed.
    ip: IPAddress
}

class User {
    id: String
    userName: String
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    email: String
    lastLogin: Date
}
```

The basic flow is

```
credentials = Credentials()
credentials->userName = "Foo"
credentials->password = "Bar"

authenticationRequest = AuthenticationRequest()
authData = await authenticationRequest->login(credentials)
credentials = NULL // Release the credentials as soon a possible

userRequest = UserRequest()
user = await userRequest->fetchCurrentUser(authData)

user->firstName = "Bob"
user->lastName = "Roberts"

// NOTE: Assigning user to the result of updateUser() allows the
//       server to control the properties of the updated user.
user = await userRequest->updateUser(user, authData)

authenticationRequest->logout(authData)
authData = NULL
```

Comment: Which code syntax is this? Python? just out of curiosity. 
`session = await authenticationRequest->login(credentials)` happens only if `authenticationRequest = AuthenticationRequest()` returns true? (just to make sure i understand. saving invalid user credentials to the session doesn't make sence...)
Having a credentials object setting to it username and pass at the begining is awesome. I sometimes do that too and get bad code reviews "why would you do that"? 
I'm guessing that the last code part is set in (for example) a login controller as a `loginFormSubmit()`?

Comment: Where you say you have a Session class, is that a Session class specifically for the UserSession handling, or a general class for Sessions? 
Because I do have a Session class, but with static methods of setting/getting/checkingIfAlreadySet sessions. 
Why is my code structure isn't ok?

Comment: From what i know, I need to have a class responsible for only one thing, so if it's setting sessions for the User, so it a UserSession class, and not to use a general class of Sessions and have all the logics there

Comment: @Kar19 The pseudo code I used was a mixture of Swift/C++/C#. Just a mishmash to show the objects and the relationships.

Comment: @Kar19 The session I created was for managing the authentication token and knowing which user is logged in. If you are doing that in another class, you don't need Session.

Comment: I get that, but I'll explain a little more, just to make sure  we understand each other. I have a `Session class {}` as you can see in my example, i have this call `Session::set` setting "something" to the session. it could be anything, just an easy way to set things to the session with a static method/helper. Do I need an other class, that sets data specifically for the `User` (`UserSession class {...}`)? or they both need to be set in the same class. Do you understand what I mean? (while having the "single responsibility principal" in mind) [tnx for your answer btw]

Comment: A class like User should be under the folder "classes" and classes like "AuthenticationRequest" & "Credentials" are under the folder "Models" (because they handle database-like stuff.

Comment: I think your session example isn't so clearto me :o

Comment: @Kar19 The sessions class I used was just a holder authentication data, I'll rename `Session` to `AuthData` if that will help avoid confusion with whatever session class you have.

Comment: @Kar19 As for your `Session` class, to have it follow the pattern I laid out, have a model as a dumb data object and have a `SessionRequest` that reads and updates the session object.